# How to write something below the css flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do something like screenshots [image: screenshot] 
you can see the boxes with name in screenshots. In my code I created the boxes but I want the boxes name below each boxes.
Please give me some hints how to achieve it?

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Flexible Boxes</h1>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div><p>box 1</p>
  <div>2</div><p>box 2</p>
  <div>3</div><p>box 3</p>  
  <div>4</div><p>box 4</p>
  <div>5</div><p>box 5</p>
  <div>6</div><p>box 6</p>  
  <div>7</div><p>box 7</p>
  <div>8</div><p>box 8</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrap each div and paragraph in separate divs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put both the box and the caption inside a div, and then make that wrapper div your flex-item. See below snippet:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.flex-container > div > p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Flexible Boxes</h1>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
   <div>1</div>
   <p>box 1</p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <div>2</div>
   <p>box 2</p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <div>3</div>
   <p>box 3</p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <div>4</div>
   <p>box 4</p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <div>5</div>
   <p>box 5</p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <div>6</div>
   <p>box 6</p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <div>7</div>
   <p>box 7</p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <div>8</div>
   <p>box 8</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put each flexbox item in its own flexbox, with flex-flow set to column:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  overflow: auto;
}

.flex-container .vflex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-container .vflex div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container .vflex p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
>
<h1>Flexible Boxes</h1>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="vflex">
    <div>1</div>
    <p>box 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="vflex">
    <div>2</div>
    <p>box 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="vflex">
    <div>3</div>
    <p>box 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="vflex">
    <div>4</div>
    <p>box 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="vflex">
    <div>5</div>
    <p>box 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="vflex">
    <div>6</div>
    <p>box 6</p>
  </div>
  <div class="vflex">
    <div>7</div>
    <p>box 7</p>
  </div>
  <div class="vflex">
    <div>8</div>
    <p>box 8</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.flex-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            background-color: DodgerBlue;
        }
        .flex-container > div {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .flex-container > div div {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            width: 100px;
            margin: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 75px;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
```

```html
.flex-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            background-color: DodgerBlue;
        }
        .flex-container > div {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .flex-container > div div {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            width: 100px;
            margin: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 75px;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
```

```css
.flex-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            background-color: DodgerBlue;
        }
        .flex-container > div {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .flex-container > div div {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            width: 100px;
            margin: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 75px;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
        <div><div>1</div><p>box 1</p></div>
        <div><div>2</div><p>box 2</p></div>
        <div><div>3</div><p>box 3</p></div>
        <div><div>4</div><p>box 4</p></div>
        <div><div>5</div><p>box 5</p></div>
        <div><div>6</div><p>box 6</p></div>
        <div><div>7</div><p>box 7</p></div>
        <div><div>8</div><p>box 8</p></div>
    </div>
```